# model diagnosis in GLMM model of binary outcome variable

Tags: r, glmm, deep-residual-networks

Dear Scientists and researchers, Greetings

I am trying to do a research article on morbidity, which is categorical, i.e., yes or no, and I also consider fixed and random effects, given that all of the fixed effect covariates are categorical. Here is the model.

twoRIM<glmer(morbidity~co_fuel+wealth+san_class+residencey+education+marital+age+parity+Electricity_avaliablity +education*age+(1|region)+(1|participant_id),family=binomial,data=M).

Hence, I try to compare these two random intercept model models to a model that has a single random intercept model based on AIC, and model "twoRIM" is the best model because it has the lowest AIC. Then I tried to check the model diagnosis of this model, mode "twoRIM", by running the following r codes, and I got the following results or plots: And the plots I got—the residual and other related plots—are quite different from other forms of model diagnosis I knew before, and I faced a bit more difficulty interpreting and understanding the nuance of these plots. Maybe I took the codes and arguments wrongly? So, dear researchers, subject matter specialists, professors, or anybody who can help me, I cannot thank you enough for your valuable idea about it. **I am waiting for your kind suggestions about these issues.**

1. scatter.smooth(fitted(twoRIM),sqrt(abs(resid(twoRIM))),col=6)

   [image]
2. qqline(resid(twoRIM))

   [image]
3. plot(twoRIM)

   [image]
4. qqnorm(resid(twoRIM),main="Residual normal plot",col=4,adj=0.1)

   [image]
5. qqnorm(ranef(twoRIM)$"region"[[1]],main="Regional level random effects",col=2,adj=0.1)
6. [image]6.qqnorm(ranef(twoRIM)$"participant_id"[[1]],main="Cluster level random effects",col=6,adj=0.1) [image]

7 plot(fitted(twoRIM),resid(twoRIM),col=4)

[image]

8.qqnorm(resid(twoRIM))

[image]

my questions is about model diagnosis in GLMM

Comment: hi! pleaseusespaces because itiseasiertoread. 
Surround your operators like `<-`, `=` or `+` with spaces. Also, `, ` likes to be followed by a space as in usual English. 
Regarding your question, maybe try to ask it on CrossValidated, which is a forum for statistics questions. Maybe you will receive more help over there, as not so many people here are model diagnosis experts but rather R language experts. It seems like you do not have a problem applying the right code to get a result, it seems to be about interpreting the result.

Comment: yeah the model is like this twoRIM<-glmer(morbidity~co_fuel+wealth+san_class+residencey+education+marital+age+parity+Electricity_avaliablity +education*age+(1|region)+(1|participant_id),family=binomial,data=M).

Comment: please edit your question accordingly and put the model code inside code fences.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`performance`-package](https://easystats.github.io/performance) to assess model fit, inspect fit indices and test models for statistically significant differences.

The *performance* package (part of the [easystats-framework](https://easystats.github.io/easystats), simply `install.packages("easystats")`) can deal with many different model classes. There are some documentations for the different functions, for example [here](https://easystats.github.io/performance/articles/check_model.html) how to interpret the diagnostic plots.

For logistic regression models, the residual plots are often less useful. Instead, either use the *DHARMa* package for more appropriate plots, or using `check_models()`, focus on the *binned residuals* and *posterior predictive checks*. The help files (see `?binned_residuals`, or online [here](https://easystats.github.io/performance/reference/binned_residuals.html)) provides more background and literature.

```r
library(performance)
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix

model1 <- glmer(vs ~ wt + (1 | gear), data = mtcars, family = "binomial")
model2 <- glmer(vs ~ wt + mpg + (1 | gear), data = mtcars, family = "binomial")

# check model assumption
check_model(model2)
```

[image]

```r
# simple comparison of fit indicess
model_performance(model1)
#> # Indices of model performance
#> 
#> AIC    |   AICc |    BIC | R2 (cond.) | R2 (marg.) |   ICC |  RMSE | Sigma | Log_loss | Score_log | Score_spherical
#> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> 35.723 | 36.580 | 40.120 |      0.627 |      0.459 | 0.310 | 0.352 | 1.000 |    0.382 |   -11.180 |           0.080
compare_performance(model1, model2)
#> # Comparison of Model Performance Indices
#> 
#> Name   |    Model | AIC (weights) | AICc (weights) | BIC (weights) | R2 (cond.) | R2 (marg.) |   ICC |  RMSE | Sigma | Log_loss | Score_log | Score_spherical
#> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> model1 | glmerMod |  35.7 (0.224) |   36.6 (0.282) |  40.1 (0.375) |      0.627 |      0.459 | 0.310 | 0.352 | 1.000 |    0.382 |   -11.180 |           0.080
#> model2 | glmerMod |  33.2 (0.776) |   34.7 (0.718) |  39.1 (0.625) |      0.703 |      0.643 | 0.170 | 0.341 | 1.000 |    0.347 |   -15.116 |           0.098

# test for statistical significant difference
test_likelihoodratio(model1, model2)
#> # Likelihood-Ratio-Test (LRT) for Model Comparison (ML-estimator)
#> 
#> Name   |    Model | df | df_diff | Chi2 |     p
#> -----------------------------------------------
#> model1 | glmerMod |  3 |         |      |      
#> model2 | glmerMod |  4 |       1 | 4.49 | 0.034
test_performance(model1, model2)
#> Name   |    Model |   BF
#> ------------------------
#> model1 | glmerMod |     
#> model2 | glmerMod | 1.67
#> Models were detected as nested (in terms of fixed parameters) and are compared in sequential order.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>